# How to pass a boolean param in laravel through url?

Tags: laravel, routes

I need to pass a param like "**link/page?url=true**" or "**link/page?url=false**"

How can I set it in my route file?

```
Route::get('/link/page', 'TestController@index')->defaults('_config', [
            'view' => 'test::home.page.index'
        ])->name('test.home.page.index');
```

Comment: `/link/page/{boolean_value}`... ?

Answer (score 0):

If the param is going to be a query parameter, then there is no need to define it in the Route file. In the controller you can fetch the param as:

```
$request->query('url');
```

But if you really want the parameter to part of the URL itself then you can define it like this:

```
Route::get('/link/page/{url}', 'TestController@index')
```

and to fetch it in controller you have to do this:

```
TestController {
     public function index($url){
          //put your logic.
     }
}
```